# Why buttons (HTML and CSS) are loading properly locally on pc, but not when uploaded to the VPS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and noticed that my buttons that are linked to other websites loads properly when loading locally on my computer in chrome but when I upload them to my VPS which is using Direct Admin as the control panel it only shows plain text that are hyperlinked. Anyone know why this would be?

Pictures attached:

[VPS loaded, same exact html and css files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LrgK.png)[loaded locally on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdCgX.png)

I have tried deleting the files completely from the VPS and re-uploading, restarting the VPS. Still having the issue.

```css
.useful-resources {
  text-align: center;
}

.useful-resources h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">Breakfast Menu</a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">Lunch Menu</a>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">School Closures</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post actual code not links to pictures ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Comment: HTML:   <div class="button-container">
        <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">Breakfast Menu</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">Lunch Menu</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a href="url" target="_blank" class="button">School Closures</a>
    </div>

Comment: CSS: .useful-resources {
  text-align: center;
}

.useful-resources h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

Comment: Don't post your codes in the comment section. Try to edit your post and include it there, or try to make an snippet.

Comment: The code posted in the comments does NOT reproduce the issue here - see the snippet I created for you from those.  For clarity you do NOT have buttons but have `<a>` elements styled as buttons (why people do this is that they follow some on-line practice instead of inserting the `<a>` inside the `<button type="button"` which was I believe the original intent of the markup to properly structure your HTML. **Please clarify what you mean by VPS here**